# How do I use `:jumps` in vim? How can I go back to a certain jump point in the past?

Tags: vim

I saw https://medium.com/@kadek/understanding-vims-jump-list-7e1bfc72cdf0. So when I did `:jumps`, I could see the jumps in the past and in the future from where I am. I wanted to go back to the jump 6 in the past.

```
:jumps
 jump line  col file/text

  12     1    0 /tmp/uu
  11    10    0 /tmp/uu
  10  4832   27 * Writing CBASER resets CREADR to 0, so make CWRITER and
   9   128   63 arch/arm64/include/asm/io.h
   8   125   41 arch/arm64/include/asm/arch_gicv3.h
   7  2284   11 gits_write_baser(val, its->base + GITS_BASER + (idx << 3));
   6  5011    1 its->base = its_base;
   5  4967    0
   4  4680   11 its->pre_its_base = pre_its_window[0];
   3  4968   25 static int __init its_probe_one(struct resource *res,
   2  5238    2 its_probe_one(&res, &np->fwnode, of_node_to_nid(np));
   1  5233   37 if (of_address_to_resource(np, 0, &res)) {
>
```

But when I type `6g;` as the above link said, nothing happens. What should I do to go back to 6 times back? (6 times ctrl-o).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go back (up in the list), enter the jump number and then `CTRL-O`. To go forward (down in the list), enter the jump number and then `CTRL-I` (or Tab).

See `:help jumps` for more information.

Comment: Oh that was it. Thank you! I don't know why the original link didn't show it. And welcome to stackoverflow!